# Printing a multi dimensional array using Foreach loop only

Tags: php, arrays

```
$info = array(
    "pandu nagar"  => array("ravi","ramesh","sunil"),
    "sharda nagar" => array("neeta","meeta","ritu")
);
```

I want to print output like-

> Area pandu nagar and person located ravi
>
> Area pandu nagar and person located ramesh
>
> Area pandu nagar and person located sunil

---

> Area sharda nagar and person located neeta
>
> Area sharda nagar and person located meeta
>
> Area sharda nagar and person located ritu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about this :

```
foreach ($info as $name => $locations) {
    foreach ($locations as $location) {
        echo "Area {$name} and person located {$location}<br />";
    }
}
```

Which means :

- One loop for the first dimension of the array,
- and, then, one loop for the second dimension -- iterating over the data gotten from the first one.

Answer (score 2):

And for printing array with one more index name:

```
$info = array (
    "00500" => array( "0101" => "603", "0102" => "3103", "0103" => "2022"),
    "01300" => array( "0102" => "589", "0103" => "55"),
    "02900" => array( "0101" => "700", "0102" => "3692", "0103" => "2077")
);
```

You can do this:

```
foreach ($info as $key => $values) {

    foreach ($values as $anotherkey => $val) {
        echo 'key:'.$key. ' AnotherKey: '.$anotherkey.' value:'.$val.'<br>';
    }

}
```

output will be:

```
key:00500 AnotherKey: 0101 value:603 
key:00500 AnotherKey: 0102 value:3103 
key:00500 AnotherKey: 0103 value:2022 
key:01300 AnotherKey: 0102 value:589 
key:01300 AnotherKey: 0103 value:55 
key:02900 AnotherKey: 0101 value:700 
key:02900 AnotherKey: 0102 value:3692 
key:02900 AnotherKey: 0103 value:2077
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($info as $key => $values) {   
    foreach ($values as $anotherkey => $val) {
        echo 'key:'.$key. ' AnotherKey: '.$anotherkey.' value:'.$val.'<br>';
    }
}
```

best way to resolve this problem