# Simpler Way To List Array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing a multi dimensional array using Foreach loop only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611483/printing-a-multi-dimensional-array-using-foreach-loop-only)
>   [Merge multiple associative arrays to a single array of associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873951/merge-multiple-associative-arrays-to-a-single-array-of-associative-arrays)

I have a script that loops scraping links from different pages and places them into an array with different keys. Now I want the script to echo all the final links into a list. As of now the only way I know to do this is like this:

```
foreach($matches[0][1] as $match) {
   echo "$match<br />";
}

foreach($matches[1][1] as $match) {
  echo "$match<br />";
}

foreach($matches[2][1] as $match) {
  echo "$match<br />";
}
```

How can I have it do something where I don't have to do a foreach loop for each array key. Something like

```
foreach($matches[ALL][1] as $match) {
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611483/printing-a-multi-dimensional-array-using-foreach-loop-only

Comment: http://brianhaveri.github.com/Underscore.php/

Answer (score 1):

This wil work

```
foreach($matches as $var)
{
  foreach($var[1] as $match)
  {
    echo "$match<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
foreach($matches as $match) {
  foreach($match[1] as $m) {
    echo $m . "<br />";
  }
}
```

That's it: Iterate over the first level array (`$matches`) and get the values. Those values are also arrays, so you can access the `[1]` item.

If you need the index for the first array, modify the loop like this:

```
foreach($matches as $k => $match) {
  foreach($match[1] as $m) {
    echo $k . ": " . $m . "<br />";
  }
}
```

Hope that helped!